# What is Verdaccio's default login?

Tags: verdaccio

Back in the day `admin:admin` worked, but that results in an `access denied`. `verdaccio:verdaccio` does not work as well. The Dockerfile does not seem to contain a default password as well.

**Command**

```
docker run -it --rm --name verdaccio -p 4873:4873 verdaccio/verdaccio
```

**Log**

```
 http <-- 401, user: null(172.17.0.1), req: 'POST /-/verdaccio/login', error: ba
d username/password, access denied
 http <-- 401, user: null(172.17.0.1), req: 'POST /-/verdaccio/login', error: ba
d username/password, access denied
 http <-- 401, user: null(172.17.0.1), req: 'POST /-/verdaccio/login', error: ba
d username/password, access denied
```

**GitHub**

https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/issues/1599

**adduser**

When http://localhost:4873 is opened, an instruction is shown how to create a new user. However, this fails:

```
npm adduser --registry http://localhost:4873
Username: (admin) wow
Password: (<default hidden>)
Email: (this IS public) (jane@example.com) admin@admin.admin
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT http://localhost:4873/-/user/org.couchdb.user:wow
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
```

**Perhaps the company's proxy is causing the issue?**

After issuing `npm config set https-proxy http://company-proxy` and running the `npm adduser` again, a 403 is still returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no default password, actually none at all. You must create a new user with

```
➜ npm adduser --registry  http://localhost:4873/
Username: wow
Password: 
Email: (this IS public) verdaccio.does.ignore.email@whatever.com
Logged in as wow on http://localhost:4873/
```

Then you are logged in.

Comment: I tried several things, but the 403 persists.

Comment: If you try with a clean installation should work, if you have custom volumes or legacy I would rather check migration guides and permission issues other issues have had, check all our related issues

Comment: Running the docker on a Linux system in conjunction with issuing the `npm adduser` on the system itself results in creation of the user. Running the docker image on Windows or trying to consult the verdaccio on the corporate network fails for some reason, while telnet works and consulting via the webbrowser as well. Although a proxy was configured, the issue persists. I will run the the image in the cloud and that will work. Thanks for your help.